# Parallelize AsyncGenerators

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, generator

I am looking for a `asyncio.create_task` equivalent for `AsyncGenerator`. I want the generator to already start executing in the background, without awaiting results explicitly.

For example:

```py
async def g():
    for i in range(3):
        await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
        yield i

async def main():
    g1 = g()
    g2 = g()
    t = time.time()
    async for i in g1:
        print(i, time.time() - t)
    async for i in g2:
        print(i, time.time() - t)
```

This takes 6 seconds to execute:

```
0 1.001204013824463
1 2.0024218559265137
2 3.004373788833618
0 4.00572395324707
1 5.007828950881958
2 6.009296894073486
```

If both generators were executed in parallel, the total execution would take just ~3 seconds. What is the recommended approach here?

Comment: You are printing the result.  Each time you print, the main loop has to block to wait for the result.

Comment: This is incorrect, please see my answer. Print does not block the loop at all, it executes almost immediately.

Comment: Impossible.  It cannot print a value unless it knows what the value is, and that requires blocking until the coroutine yields another value.

Comment: Yes, but the 2 generators can execute in parallel, so we can reduce the total execution time from 6 seconds to 3 (as I am showing is possible in my answer). The print itself is non-blocking you can change it to pass and it will be still 6 seconds. The block in within the async loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the approach I came up with:

```py
async def consume(a_iter: AsyncIterator) -> Tuple[Any, Optional[asyncio.Task]]:
    try:
        return await a_iter.__anext__(),  asyncio.create_task(consume(a_iter))
    except StopAsyncIteration:
        return None, None

def create_generator_task(gen: AsyncGenerator) -> AsyncGenerator:
    result_queue = asyncio.create_task(consume(gen.__aiter__()))
    async def consumer():
        nonlocal result_queue
        while 1:
            item, result_queue = await result_queue
            if result_queue is None:
                assert item is None
                return
            yield item
    return consumer()
```

In case there is not any official solution in standard library that I am missing, this method works pretty well. **Example:**

```py
async def main():
    g1 = create_generator_task(g())
    g2 = create_generator_task(g())
    t = time.time()
    async for i in g1:
        print(i, time.time() - t)
    async for i in g2:
        print(i, time.time() - t)
```

Prints:

```
0 1.0013220310211182
1 2.002387046813965
2 3.0078349113464355
0 3.00785493850708
1 3.007858991622925
2 3.007862091064453
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to create two tasks and run them in parallel.  Here is one way to do that.  That each task involves an asynchronous generator is not significant.

```
import asyncio
import time

async def g():
    for i in range(3):
        await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
        yield i
        
async def a_task(t):
    async for i in g():
        print(i, time.time() - t)

async def main():
    t = time.time()
    await asyncio.gather(a_task(t), a_task(t))
    print("Total time", time.time() - t)
    
asyncio.run(main())
```

Result:

```
0 1.0009820461273193
0 1.0009820461273193
1 2.001558303833008
1 2.001558303833008
2 3.001593828201294
2 3.001593828201294
```

In your example you print the individual items from the first loop before starting the second loop, but I assume that isn't what you really want.

Comment: Thanks, as stated in the question: "I am looking for a asyncio.create_task equivalent for AsyncGenerator". The approach you suggest will not allow for example iterating through them in parallel or interleaving the elements easily. This will not work for example in grpc streaming response.